# I can't reinstall TeX Live 2020 anymore

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I had to reinstall Windows 10 due to... reasons, but now I can't reinstall TeX Live 2020 anymore.

Here an example of the parts of the log which gives errors:

```
Installing [2194/3989, time/total: 33:29/01:02:36]: luahbtex.win32 [1515k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\DdaEAW72eM\fGSW0JDB9m/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=5e395b24bd9e710be88f1f2e2a3bd18022daf3cf1e2be18d27192eccea50f5ddaa122c6ae8cd4cce6b54d3a8608ae9e119d0dbf25d1e37aa2da8a986aa0a0c70, arg=04f90e04de858fb120852cebd84671f026b355fd1ac1acb5fee48f559f06709f8c25fa4f2ccf84a602de92ff728de5bfdc97610325c803540b349c2c3f1faf18
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1552: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\DdaEAW72eM\fGSW0JDB9m/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\VmR0fPlQ0O
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install luahbtex.win32
Will be retried later.
Installing [2195/3989, time/total: 33:29/01:02:36]: luahyphenrules [41k]
Installing [2196/3989, time/total: 33:30/01:02:37]: luaimageembed [3k]
Installing [2197/3989, time/total: 33:31/01:02:39]: luaindex [175k]
Installing [2198/3989, time/total: 33:32/01:02:41]: luainputenc [414k]
Installing [2199/3989, time/total: 33:34/01:02:44]: luaintro [31k]
Installing [2200/3989, time/total: 33:35/01:02:45]: luajittex [31k]
Installing [2201/3989, time/total: 33:36/01:02:47]: luajittex.win32 [2143k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\DdaEAW72eM\YHCvF6Ovnj/luajittex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=d1649342c5f398c1b843a392a7109760abeac59dbb3047d09d3c35c38450247cf6c705165334ef5fa48211871ee5686f19e66f91dd6237bd5840e6de6081ed4a, arg=ea5adb47694ee0f19692c47101a08be3b58587da38aa380358bad58665f864e90da149b8c940d1144cbed9bcd735531c885fb2a781683261a0dda26962d03563
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1552: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\DdaEAW72eM\YHCvF6Ovnj/luajittex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\EKOsppJq2Z
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luajittex.win32.tar.xz
TLUtils::install_packages: Failed to install luajittex.win32
Will be retried later.
Installing [2202/3989, time/total: 33:36/01:02:47]: lualatex-doc [126k]
```

and the log ends with:

```
Installing [3989/3989, time/total: 02:05:21/02:05:41]: zxjatype [144k]
Retrying to install: luahbtex.win32 [1515k]
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\DdaEAW72eM\AweI_6xZCS/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=5e395b24bd9e710be88f1f2e2a3bd18022daf3cf1e2be18d27192eccea50f5ddaa122c6ae8cd4cce6b54d3a8608ae9e119d0dbf25d1e37aa2da8a986aa0a0c70, arg=04f90e04de858fb120852cebd84671f026b355fd1ac1acb5fee48f559f06709f8c25fa4f2ccf84a602de92ff728de5bfdc97610325c803540b349c2c3f1faf18
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2330: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1976: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1811: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1727: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:1566: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:2160: TeXLive::TLUtils::install_packages
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:980: main::do_install_packages
 -> C:/Users/Carla/AppData/Local/Temp/nsi28A4.tmp/install-tl-20200512/install-tl:732: main::do_installation
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\DdaEAW72eM\AweI_6xZCS/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\Carla\AppData\Local\Temp\Ys67QyWzFF
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/luahbtex.win32.tar.xz
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
or
  install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]
```

Comment: Maybe try rerunning with `install-tl-windows.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]` or `install-tl-advanced.bat --profile installation.profile [YOUR-EXTRA-ARGS]` like it says to. (Look at the very bottom)

Comment: @Someone I don't know what are the `[YOUR_EXTRA_ARGS]`

Comment: Karl wrote on the texlive list that he forced an update of the broken packages but I don't see yet a repository which has it. So I think your best chance is to restart the installer and to choose a small scheme which doesn't contain the three luatex binary packages (if that exists)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good, no problem, I'll wait. I was scared it was a problem of my pc!

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Did you try Vegard's solution? Does it work?

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer I'm a bit skeptical too, we have to wait, then.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer The problem is solved now, I've just managed to install TeX Live 2020.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ^^^ Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: In 2020 I was thinking TeX Live would be more robust regarding such failures (the chances of it happening with 4020 files is not small!). It's happened to me on linux now after 3 hours. I understand why downloading an ISO works (the robustness is built in for a long time to get big files over the internet).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the same error messages reinstalling TexLive, both on clean Windows and during an upgrade.

As a workaround, you may download the TexLive2020 ISO and use it instead of the network installer which is searching the latest package repo. Present ISO has date 2020-04-06.
You may find the download at CTAN Directory systems/texlive/Images or follow the link:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images

After mounting the image, run the "install-tl-windows.bat" as admin and follow normal install (verify that the install is pointing to the ISO and not net.repo).

Comment: And of course: after installation is complete, you may use the TeX Live Manager to update the packages to latest network repo. 

I have tested with updating all packages but i avoided ".Win32" packages as the "luahbtex.win32"/"luajittex.win32 " and similar

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does this method give the same result as the usual installer?

Comment: Yes - exactly the same result in the end and also during the installation process, however, a bit speedier since the download is already done

You just avoid the packages suspected with errors currently in the remote repo.

When inside the Tex Live Manager(after installation) I see the suspected packages:
"luahbtex.win32"/"luajittex.win32 " are in rev. 54250 locally, while in remote repo they are in 55114.
So I will avoid updating these packages until a new rev. is available in remote repo.
All other packages were updated successfully, and I tested my installation trough some documents

Comment: If the error is still present tomorrow, I'll try.

Comment: No problem - maybe the issue is fixed then.

Just as a note: The ISO at CTAN consists of the official release of Tex Live 2020, so the only added value by the network installer is that you directly get latest updates of packages. A task you can do after the installation, and that I do regulary, trough Tex Live Manager

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add the command(s) to get the latest updates over the network?

Comment: Hi! I hope I can answer you directly instead of editing the answer as "luahbtex.win32"/"luajittex.win32" now is fixed all packages may be updated.

To update packages after install (windows):
1. Open TeX Live Manager,

2. Select "Options->Repository->Any CTAN mirror" and "Save and Load". External mirror is searched trough your area/selected repo.

3. Press updatable and select packages - "Update marked" or "Update all".

4. Wait untill bottom left indicator shifts from "Running" to "Done"

If fresh you may use the network installer: https://www.tug.org/texlive/

Hope it clarifies